# Creating selected scroll buttons with css/jquery.

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I am building a landing page that has 3 sections. Each section is a full page section ( `width:100%;` x `height:100%` of the browser ) div with it's own ID. I have a target in each that when pressed, `scrollTo`'s the proper section.

```
<div class="page-section clear" id="Welcome">
    <div class="wrapper clear">
        <a href="#we-are-the-leader" class="downW">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page-section clear" id="we-are-the-leader">
    <div class="wrapper clear">
        <a href="#Services" class="downW">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page-section clear" id="Services">
    <div class="wrapper clear">
        <a href="#Services" class="downW">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

            var navBarHeight = 0; // change if nav bar height changes
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': ($target.offset().top - navBarHeight)
            }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuint', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is working perfectly for me, but now I want to add three css 'buttons' that are a certain color when the section they are associated with is selected. I know it's going to utilize the same concept as I've already implemented, but I'm learning jQuery and am not sure about the best way to do this in relation with the existing `scroll` function.

Comment: Do you want the three buttons to be always visible, no matter which section is currently shown? That's what it sounds like, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @DuncanThacker yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Change the css class of the button in the animate callback:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var buttons = $('a[href^="#"]');
        var clearAllSelected = function () {
            $.each(buttons, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('.selected-class').addClass('.unselected-class');
            });
        };
        buttons.on('click',function (e) {
            clearAllSelected ();
            var button = $(this);

            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

            var navBarHeight = 0; // change if nav bar height changes
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': ($target.offset().top - navBarHeight)
            }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuint', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                button.removeClass('.unselected-class')
                   .addClass('.selected-class');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach for styling them - I like to use HTML attributes for this sort of thing. This means you don't have to do `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. So you could create your buttons like this:

```
<div class='lovely-buttons'>
    <button data-section-id=1>1</button>
    <button data-section-id=2>2</button>
    <button data-section-id=3>3</button>
</div>
```

(You can use section names if you prefer, but numbers works fine). Then:

```
$(".lovely-buttons").on("click", "button", function(e) {

     var sectionIdToScrollTo = $(this).attr("data-section-id");
     scrollToSection(sectionIdToScrollTo); //as in your code
     $("body").attr("data-current-section", sectionIdToScrollTo);

});
```

Now the `<body>` element should have an attribute telling us what the currently visible section is, and we can use it for CSS rules:

```
/* make all buttons grey by default,
   and make them transition at the same speed as the scroll */
.lovely-buttons button {
    background-color: #888; 
    transiton: background-color 1s ease;
}

/* make the button that matches the current section RED */
[data-current-section=1] button[data-section-id=1],
[data-current-section=2] button[data-section-id=2],
[data-current-section=3] button[data-section-id=3] {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Now your buttons will change color as the animation takes place.

Comment: The only thing I am confused about it is what you mean with this:"scrollToSection(sectionIdToScrollTo); //as in your code". I'm assuming this is the part where I need to assign my sections to a button?

Comment: No, that's where you scroll the page to the section that's been selection (hence the name `scrollToSection`).

Comment: I am sorry but I'm still confused about how to implement the html of the sections with the ids from the buttons. I'm also not sure if you are suggesting that I alter my existing scroll script to mesh with what you wrote. Upon further inspection your solution seems incomplete.  Is there something I'm missing? What you sent is not working for me.

Comment: Here's what you should do (I'd do it for you, but I don't have enough of your code):
(1) Add the "lovely-buttons" div to your HTML
(2) In CSS, give it `position:fixed` to make sure it's always visible on the screen
(3) Change the data-section-id attributes on the buttons to match up with the ones on your sections
(4) Write the `scrollToSection` function so that it scrolls to the section with the appropriate name.

Comment: You have my script code in the question. I'm still confused if I get rid of what I originally had completely and add it to the script you wrote or keep both? Can you please clarify that? Really not sure how replace '//as in your code'. The html part is clear now, however. <div class="buttons">
       <button data-section-id=Welcome>1</button>
      <button data-section-id=We-Are-The-Leader>2</button>
      <button data-section-id=Services>3</button>
  </div>